# Zipkin Client can not connect to the Zipkin Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, zipkin

I have started zipkin-server and I can see the dashboard. I have tested it with simple projects and it is okay. But when I test it with my app I have a problem. I have Spring Boot project that produce to kafka if the property for kafka is set on true in application.properties. In my case it is always set to false and it is working correctly. But when I added zipkin dependency it start to send to kafka. And also I can not see my client app in the zipkin dashboard. I am using Spring Boot 1.5.6.RELEASE version

This are my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

And this are my properties for zipkin and sleuth.

```
#Sleuth
spring.sleuth.scheduled.enabled=false
spring.sleuth.async.enabled=false
spring.sleuth.annotation.enabled=false
spring.sleuth.enabled = true 
spring.sleuth.sampler.probability=1.0
#Zipkin
spring.zipkin.baseUrl = http://localhost:9411 
logging.pattern.level=%d{ABSOLUTE} [%X{X-B3-TraceId}/%X{X-B3-SpanId}] %-5p [%t] %C{2} - %m%n
```

By adding the first 3 properties the application is not sending requests on the beggining, but it start after I send a request to my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change all properties with this:

```
#Sleuth
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0
#Zipkin
spring.zipkin.sender.type=web
```

spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage=1.0 is Edgware
so you need that

baseUrl by default is localhost